# How can I load images received from iMessage? [iOS7]

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, ios7, imessage

I am trying to load the images received from a contact in iMessage, but I have not found in iOS SDK to do this.

- Load the contents of incoming iMessages.
- Load the images received by iMessage.

Someone who knows how to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done with on iOS with the iOS SDK. Due to privacy concerns Apple does not allow access to any messages received via the messages.app.

Comment: hi @rckoenes, Is it now possible with iOS 10?

Comment: Nope, Apple will never allow access to iMessage, this poses a very big privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to pull images directly from the Messages app, then no you can't do that. If however, you're okay with only viewing the images that the user has chosen to save to the camera roll, then yes you have a few options.

You can use the [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) class to allow the user to select photos from their camera roll, or the [AssetsLibrary Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) to get references to these images without the user selecting them. Both solutions do require the user granting you access to the camera roll though.